# Multiple polymorphic association search using Ransack, is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, filter, ransack

I have the class `Invoice` that `belongs_to` `Invoiceable`, a polymorphic class. The `Invoiceable` of Invoice can either be `Subscription` or `Purchase`.

I need to be able to search by the status of an Invoice's `Subscription` or `Purchase`.

I'm trying the following to no success:

```
<%= f.check_box :invoiceable_of_Subscription_or_Purchase_type_status_in, { multiple: true }, type[1], false %>
```

I tried different combinations like:

```
<%= f.check_box :invoiceable_of_Subscription_type_or_invoiceable_of_Purchase_type_status_in, { multiple: true }, type[1], false %>
```

But I always get a `Polymorphic associations do not support computing the class.` error.

Is this possible? Ransack documentation only explains how to search by a single polymorphic associated model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close to the answer.

You need to specify column name with each of the polymorphic association

use below combination :

```
<%= f.check_box :invoiceable_of_Subscription_type_status_or_invoiceable_of_Purchase_type_status_in, { multiple: true }, type[1], false %>
```

Reference : https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Polymorphic-searches